# Rendering particles only inside an object?

Tags: rendering, modifiers, particles

So Im trying to render a ship inside a bottle with ocean and foam. 
[image: without the particles]
[image: with the particles]
The particles in this project are supposed to be foam on the ocean. To only render the fluid inside the bottle I used an boolean modifier. I tried to do the same for the particles but I guess as there are 440k particles it takes way to much resources and blender crashes trying to calculate it. So my question is: is there another way to render particles only inside a particular object? I couldnt really find an answer anywhere online or in the documentation of blender.

Comment: You can give a mask in the layers tab. Please share your blend file so that I can take a look at it? You can do this by uploading the blend file on this site - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and copy + pasting the generated url here.

Comment: I cant really get the blend to be under 60 mb so I cant upload it.. Can you explain what you mean? I have never worked with masks before